# Free mailing list provider for open source projects?

Tags: communication

Are there any providers of mailing lists for open source projects?

I know of the following so far:

- Savannah
- Sourceforge

Savannah requires a GPL project (and that is ok), but the process of getting accepted takes forever.
SourceForge is getting worse and worse. Never liked it in the first place.

Anything else? Anything better?

Comment: You could look into google groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!overview , which does (also) function as a traditional mailinglist. This is free as in beer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a software recommendation request.

Comment: It's about a service recommendation question, highly relevant to any serious effort for developing open source software. It's hard to have a universally accessible discussion without a mailing list.

Comment: As pointed out the OP, it is actually a *service*  recommendation request. However, I don't see how a request for free (as in beer) stuff is going to be on-topic here no matter how serious and noble the cause, including a "serious effort for developing open source software" . What makes a free mailing list for open source different from a free mailing list for trainspotters? (I'll change my mind if the OP can point out what, beside the purpose, makes an mailing list for open source different).

Comment: "Open source" is a movement, a community & development style which promotes access not just to the source code but also it's development process. "Open source software" is the product of those communities. A mailing list can be used for many purposes, including open source development. Since it can be so critical to the proceedings of open source, assuming it is the preferred method of discussion, it's worth covering available mediums in this exchange.

Comment: For this to have any chance of being on-topic it would need to have a lot more detailed criteria to judge any suggestions by. As it is, it is an open ended list question, which are off-topic every on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Please suggest such criteria. I reasoned why this is on-topic but I'm happy to add more aspects to the question if that helps.

Comment: We need to sort out the criteria: I've taken this to meta: http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/489/shall-requests-for-free-stuff-be-on-topic-as-long-as-it-is-free-stuff-for-open - the post include *examples* of the type of criteria I would like to see to have question about service providers on-topic.

Comment: "which are off-topic every on the Stack Exchange", and also universally the first results on google...

Answer (score 3):

If all you want is a mailing list, you could use [FreeLists](http://www.freelists.org/) which specifically states that it is not just free as in beer.  They use [ecartis](http://www.ecartis.net/) as a mailing list manager and not Mailman which you might be familiar with, but they are both free as in freedom.